# How to make sure client doesn't sync when switching from dev to live server

Tags: gun

When I change the url in the client from localhost to myLiveServer.com, how do I make sure that the localStorage doesn't get synced with the live data?
Do I need to configure that somewhere and extend the url like...
localhost:8080/gun/dev and myLiveServer.com/gun/live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is probably wise to do something like this:

```
var gun = Gun('http://localhost:8080/gun').get('development');
```

And then in production, do something like:

```
var gun = Gun('http://myserver.com/gun').get('uniqueAppName');
```

Great question though, maybe this is something we can improve/make easier in the future.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Maybe make this a mandatory setting, so developers don't forget to "namespace" their servers